# upload file ajax without form and submited (automatic)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have file input `<input type="file" class="form-control fileStyle" id="invoice" name="invoice">`
and this is my jquery (i dont know it's work or not)

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('formData', file);
$.ajax({
    url: host+'upload/file',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

But my problem it's on upload/file I dont know how to call my file input? Any sugesttion?

NOTE : I'm using framework like `ci` or `laravel` like that.

UPDATE :
Nevermind case closed i figured out, i call $_FILES to get everything.

Comment: You mean... `var file = document.getElementById("invoice").files[0]` ?

Comment: you mean you don't know how to read the uploaded file on the server-side? Please clarify. You mention laravel or ci - which one are you using? It might change things. But they are both PHP, there are plenty of tutorials online about how to process file uploads in PHP.

Comment: @ADyson yep, well is not my framework. Is my ex partner workshoop. He left early so i sont know he using laravel or ci. Anyway i was trying use $_POST or $_File but didnt call the my input file.